# How do I do unit testing for oracle stored procedure call in spring boot JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and have Oracle stored procedure calls. How do I do unit testing and code coverage for this scenario.  Below is sample code

```
StoredProcedureQuery userProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("STOREDPROCNAME");
String param1 = "p_search_string";
String param2 = "p_start_position";
String param3 = "P_worday_users";


userProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(param1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
userProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(param2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
userProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(param3, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
userProcedure.setParameter(param1, searchText);

List<Object[]> results = userProcedure.getResultList();
```

1. Can I use in memory db instead oracle for unit testing?
2. How to do  unit testing for native query?

   @Query(value = "SELECT SCHEMA.ID_SEQ.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)
   public int getPkgIdSeq();